# Puppet: Force refresh of the autosign list?

Tags: puppet

I'm using the Policy autosigning in the Open-source puppet to get it run an executable before deciding whether to sign a certificate (https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/ssl_autosign.html#policy-based-autosigning).  Our executable queries an external webservice and converts the result for puppet to use.  This is worked fine, but assumes the executable's result is static.

The issue is if a host turns up and isn't instantly signed, Puppet never seems to check with the executable when the host turns up again - it remembers the previous result and doesn't sign the certificate.

Is there a way of getting puppet to call the executable every time an unsigned host attempts to get it's certificate signed, rather than just once?

Comment: For anyone that's ends up here looking for a response: 
https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/ssl_autosign.html#policy-executable-api says that this is by design and I cannot see a way of editing this in config.
Our way round this problem was to write a custom 'doorman' script to check the executable and sign certificates through the Puppet CLI - it's not elegant but it works...